# Refresh HTML Component Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular6

Im working with angular 6 and I have the following Component

MainComponent.ts which have this code on ngOnInit:

```
ngOnInit() {
   console.log('OnInit');    
   this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
     if (params['id'] != null) {
       this.id= params['id']
     }
   });
 }
```

and then this on MainComponent.HTML

```
<DataComponent [id]="id"></DataComponent>
<TableComponent [id]="id"></TableComponent>
<FieldComponent [id]="id"></FieldComponent>
```

The route is: http://localhost:4200/Data/77

It all works perfectly until I need be clone or change the ID, so I need the MainComponent refresh all the IDs..
I did the following code:

```
this.router.navigate(['/Data', result.id_cloned_data]);
```

Edit:
**Routes**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: 'Formula/:idFormula',
    component: FormulaMainComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
   },
  { path: 'Formula', component: FormulaMainComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '', component: FormulaMainComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

The URL changes to, for example: http://localhost:4200/Data/399 but the MainComponent dont refresh.
I did an EventEmitter passing the new ID to the MainComponent but its still not working and I already tried on AppRoutes onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'.

What am I doing wrong? Isnt it to reaload so each component Call its Get from API?

Comment: what happens if you put console.log(this.id) in subscribe()?

Comment: @MaciejWójcik It refresh the variable in .TS but not the HTML

Comment: Yes beacuse params created by Router only once. May be better choice use <router-outlet></router-outlet> for this component. and check id on the child level? Remember about level of <router-outlet> and params 'id'

Comment: I tried to call subscribe Params on all sub-components and it works, but I guess its not a "good code", I thought that I was doing the right thing with a main component giving the ID to the sub-components and reloading by themselves, but it didnt work the way I thought it would

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Variant 1:**

```
public bookId$: Observable<string> // 'id' is bad name for variable, remember about code readability;

ngOnInit() {  
    this.bookId$ = this.activatedRoute.paramMap.pipe(
      map((param) => {
        return param.get('BOOK_ID');
      }),
    );
 }
```

template of component:

```
<DataComponent [bookId]="bookId$ | async"></DataComponent>
<TableComponent [bookId]="bookId$| async"></TableComponent>
<FieldComponent [bookId]="bookId$ | async"></FieldComponent>.
```

**Variant 2:**

1) template of DataComponent:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

2) example of router config:

```
  {
    children: [
      {
        component: DataChildComponent,
        path: ':BOOK_ID',
      },
    ],
    component: DataComponent,
    path: 'Data',
  },
```

3) template of DataChildComponent:

```
<DataComponent [bookId]="bookId$ | async"></DataComponent>
<TableComponent [bookId]="bookId$| async"></TableComponent>
<FieldComponent [bookId]="bookId$ | async"></FieldComponent>
```

4) DataChildComponent:

```
public bookId$: Observable<string>;

ngOnInit() {  
    this.bookId$ = this.activatedRoute.paramMap.pipe(
      map((param) => {
        return param.get('BOOK_ID');
      }),
    );
 }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, but still not working, on the first call its all good, but when I change ID still not working, Im gonna try something like you said about <router-outlet>

Comment: Please show your router config, looks like problem with it.

Comment: Updated my answer. Check second variant

Comment: I updated my question, gonna try your second variant

Comment: activated router is part of url between two slashes. Components consumed this activatedroute. Remember about hierarchy. 'parent_url/child_url/' etc. so you're components should be the same hierarchy ParentComponent -> Child Component.
(sorry for my English, hope it helps)

Comment: Thanks, it worked when I called the ID on ChildComponent